# uploading remote url to server

Tags: php, url

I am using following codes to upload remote files to my server. It works great where direct download link is given but recently I have noticed that few websites are giving mysql links as download link and when we click on that link the files start downloading to my pc. But even in html source of that page it does not show the direct link.

Here is my code:

```
 <form method="post">
 <input name="url" size="50" />
 <input name="submit" type="submit" />
 </form>
 <?php
 if (!isset($_POST['submit'])) die();
 $destination_folder = 'mydownloads/';
 $url = $_POST['url'];
 $newfname = $destination_folder . basename($url);
 $file = fopen ($url, "rb");
 if ($file) {
 $newf = fopen ($newfname, "wb");

  if ($newf)
 while(!feof($file)) {
 fwrite($newf, fread($file, 1024 * 8 ), 1024 * 8 );
 }
 }

 if ($file) {
  fclose($file);
 }

if ($newf) {
fclose($newf);
}

?>
```

It works great for all links where the download link is direct for example if I will give 
     http://priceinindia.org/muzicpc/48.php?id=415508 link it will upload the music file but the file name will be 48.php?id=415508  but the actual mp3 file is stored at
     http://lq.mzc.in/data48-2/37202/Appy_Budday_(Videshi)-Santokh_Singh(www.Mzc.in).mp3

So if I can get the actual destination url the name will be Appy_Budday_(Videshi)-Santokh_Singh(www.Mzc.in).mp3

So I want to get the actual download url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the original URL is redirecting.  You want to catch the URL it is being redirected to, try using the headers and then get the basename($redirect_url) as your file name.

+1 for Robbie using CURL.

If you run (from command line)

```
[username@localhost ~]$ curl http://priceinindia.org/muzicpc/48.php?id=415508 -I
HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Server: nginx/1.0.10
Date: Wed, 19 Sep 2012 07:31:18 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.10
Location: http://lq.mzc.in/data48-2/37202/Appy_Budday_(Videshi)-Santokh_Singh(www.Mzc.in).mp3
```

You can see the location header here is the new url.

in php try something like

```
$ch = curl_init('http://priceinindia.org/muzicpc/48.php?id=415508'); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1); // return header
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false); // dont redirect 
$c = curl_exec($ch); //execute
echo curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE); // will echo http code.  302 for temp move
echo curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL); // url being redirected to
```

You want to find the location part of the header.   not sure the setting im sure though.

EDIT 3..or 4?
Yeah right, I see whats happening. You actually want to follow the location url then echo the effective url without downloading file.  try.

```
$ch = curl_init('http://priceinindia.org/muzicpc/48.php?id=415508');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
$c = curl_exec($ch); //execute
echo curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL); // url being redirected to
```

When I run this my output is

```
[username@localhost ~]$ php test.php
http://lq.mzc.in/data48-2/37202/Appy_Budday_(Videshi)-Santokh_Singh(www.Mzc.in).mp3
```

Comment: done.  you should get used to executing commands like curl from the command line.  It can be invaluable when debugging.

Comment: looks like Robbie has the setting... curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);

Comment: i am getting this as output HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily Server: nginx/1.0.10 Date: Wed, 19 Sep 2012 07:49:21 GMT Content-Type: text/html Transfer-Encoding: chunked Connection: keep-alive X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.10 Location: http://lq.mzc.in/data48-2/37202/Appy_Budday_(Videshi)-Santokh_Singh(www.Mzc.in).mp3 302  i want only url

Comment: When your building your filename check curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE) != 301 or 302 otherwise get curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL) and build the filename from that.

Answer (score 1):

You should use Curl library for this. http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

An example of how to use curl is provided in tha manual (on that link) befo before you close the connections, call curl_getinfo (http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php) and specifically get CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL which is what you want.

```
<?php
// Create a curl handle
$ch = curl_init('http://www.yahoo.com/');

// Execute
$fileData = curl_exec($ch);

// Check if any error occured
if(!curl_errno($ch)) {
    $effectiveURL = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);
}

// Close handle
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

(You can also use curl to write directly to a file - use the CURLOPT_FILE options. Also in the manual)

Comment: i added echo $effectiveURL; in your code but it returns the input url only rather than redirected url