# How to fix php Warning: file_get_contents?failed to open stream: HTTP request failed

Tags: php, file-get-contents

How to fix php Warning: file_get_contents?

```
Warning: file_get_contents(http://192.168.1.254:9999/api/p/internal/ucenter/login?loginName=test102&password=111111) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/PHP_test/index.php on line 49
```

Here is code related to $files:

```
<?php
$loginNames="test102";
$passwords="111111";
$apiUrl = "http://192.168.1.254:9999/api/p/internal/ucenter/login?loginName=".$loginNames."&password=".$passwords;
$callback = file_get_contents($apiUrl);

print_r($callback);
//echo $callback;
?>
```

Comment: Did you try it like `$callback = @file_get_contents($apiUrl); if($callback !== false) print_r($callback);`?

Comment: What happens if you go to that URL in your browser?  Are you redirected?  Try using CURL and see what the headers return.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12489499/uploading-remote-url-to-server/12489662#12489662 for similar CURL code.

Comment: use CURL (http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If this shows in your page, there's something wrong with your [`display_errors`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors) setting.

Ideally, `display_errors` should be `Off` for production machines and you should handle errors by yourself using [`set_error_handler()`](http://sg3.php.net/set_error_handler).

See also: [Error logging, in a smooth way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10331084/error-logging-in-a-smooth-way/10476589#10476589)

This particular warning can't be stopped unless you make sure the page exists. However, used in isolation, you can use the [muffle operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php) to prevent the warning from appearing:

```
if (false !== ($contents = @file_get_contents('...'))) {
    // all good
} else {
    // error happened
}
```

*Note that this will still call your custom error handler*

Answer (score 1):

I have better option for you.

Avoid `file_get_contents` , user  `cURL` .

Let me show you one example:

```
$url = 'http://www.yoururl.com';
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
$data = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

Note: Is you feel encoding problem add this: `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING ,"");`

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest try to check if url exist before you call file_get_contents.
You can ref page [How can I check if a URL exists via PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2280394/how-can-i-check-if-a-url-exists-via-php)